# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `leads` is marked as required in `Leads`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying this tutorial to display information into my table using React and Redux, but I keep on getting this error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `leads` is marked as required in
>   `Leads`, but its value is `undefined`   Uncaught Type Error: Cannot
>   read property 'map' of undefined Leads.js:52

My code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { getLeads } from "../../actions/leads";

export class Leads extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    leads: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getLeads();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h2>Leads</h2>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Message</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.props.leads.map(lead => (
              <tr key={lead.id}>
                <td>{lead.id}</td>
                <td>{lead.name}</td>
                <td>{lead.email}</td>
                <td>{lead.message}</td>
                <td><button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  leads: state.leads.leads
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getLeads }
)(Leads);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: state.leads.leads will be apparentrly undefined. check your state

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not on this Leads component, 
but the parent component who used Leads.

you must add props called leads with array format.

Comment: leads is filled from redux state.

Comment: Thank you very much but actually it was a typo in my leads.js file in my action folder and leads.js file in my reducer folder

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with

```
static propTypes = {
    leads: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

You have marked this as compulsory value to be passed when you use `Leads` component.

So you have to use like this

```
<Leads lead={[]} />
```

and empty array or some data you have to share to this component.

Comment: Thank you very much but actually it was a typo in my leads.js file in my action folder and leads.js file in my reducer folder

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you required the Prop leads

```
static propTypes = {
    leads: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

You should pass a prop when it is called as so

```
<Leads lead={[]} />
```

or change the static propTypes by removing the isRequired as so

```
 static propTypes = {
        leads: PropTypes.array,
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much but actually it was a typo in my leads.js file in my action folder and leads.js file in my reducer folder